# Rails keep saying delete route does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails keeps saying that the route to my users_controller#destroy does not exist?

Here is the markup:

```
 = button_to 'Delete', user_path(@user), method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?', class: 'small button delete'
```

Here is an extract from routes.rb:

```
resources :users, except: [:show]
```

Here is an extract from users_controllers.rb:
  # DELETE /users/1

```
 def destroy
    if current_user.id != @user.id
      raise('A user may not delete their own account')
    end

    @user.destroy!
    redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully deleted.'
  end
```

and here an extract from the error message that I keep getting:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/users"

new_user_path    GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path   GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path    PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT  /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
```

Comment: Have you tried with `link_to`?

Comment: Is it possible that @user is nil?

Comment: you're not passing any id

Comment: @MurifoX yes, but it makes no difference

Comment: @davidrac, that is the right answer, it is supposed to be user, and not @@user. I really dont know why I have RubyMine if it can't show stupid mistakes like any other ide.

Comment: @apneadiving you don't have to, it retrieves it off the model object.

Comment: :) yeah, not talking about your code, just about the debug output: `No route matches [DELETE] "/users"`

Comment: :) I just realised myself what you meant.

Comment: is it a typo here or your controller file name is really user_controllers.rb?

Comment: It is a typo. I have since corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

@davidrac, and @apneadiving both gave the correct answer in the comments above, it is because `@user` should be `user`